# Plots without titles/labels in R

Tags: r, plot, charts, statistics

In [R](http://www.r-project.org/) is there any way to produce plots which have no title and which use the space the title would otherwise have taken up?

In `plot()`, `main`, `sub`, `xlab`, and `ylab` all default to `NULL`, but this just leaves blank space where they would have been, ditto for setting them to ''.  It would be nice if not including them meant that the entire plot space was utilized rather than leaving extra empty space on the edges.  This is all especially relevant in printing plots to file devices like `pdf()`, `png()`, etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See [tip 7](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html) about adjusting the margins.

Excerpt:

To remove the space reserved for labels, use par(mar=...).  For example

```
png(file="notitle.png",width=400, height=350)
par(mar=c(5,3,2,2)+0.1)
hist(rnorm(100),ylab=NULL,main=NULL)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 15):

If you're willing to entertain an alternate plotting package, [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) does this automatically when you set `xlab`/`ylab` to `NULL` (and there is no plot title/`main` by default).  For simple plots, just `require(ggplot2)` and replace `plot` by `qplot`.

Really, ggplot2 is the most fun I've had with plotting in years and I can't resist the opportunity to evangelize it to everyone I meet. :-)

Answer (score 5):

With lattice, it's just a matter of setting the xlab, ylab, and main arguments to NULL:

```
library(lattice)
bwplot(rnorm(100),xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,main=NULL)
```

Comment: Alas, when I set xlab=NULL... it shows an 'x' ... and continues to render the space that i'd rather were consumed entirely by histogram bars.  This is quite vexing.

Answer (score 4):

```
plot(anything, main=NULL)
```

Still works.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! The question was not whether it works (the OP knows that), but how to use the empty space. Please read the questions and the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) carefully before answering.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
```

when I keep the border to a minimum.